# How to add an extra column with different time zone

Tags: mysql

I have created a simple SQL script. The script gives the latest chats, but I want to see multiple time zones. One time zone where the server is located and one time zone where I live. So I want an extra column that converts the 'msg_time' to UTC+1. I have searched for some time now, but can't find the solution.
Does anyone know how to add this to my script?

```
SELECT `msg`, FROM_UNIXTIME(`chatlog`.`msg_time`), `client_name` 
FROM `chatlog` 
order by FROM_UNIXTIME(`chatlog`.`msg_time`) DESC
```

Comment: Hi Wassie, this question may be better fitted for the DBA StackExchange site for your answer. Is this related to what you're asking? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123835/how-to-convert-timezone-in-mysql-using-the-timezone-name

Comment: Also, what are you currently storing, and what is the current timezone you are storing things on? Eventually in order to change timezone you will need to use [`CONVERT_TZ`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) for what you want

Comment: thanks a lot, your code works like a charme!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new column like the following:

```
SELECT `msg`,
       FROM_UNIXTIME(`chatlog`.`msg_time`) as `msg_time`,
       CONVERT_TZ(`chatlog`.`msg_time`, 'GMT', 'Europe/Paris') as `msg_time_local`, 
       `client_name` 
FROM `chatlog` 
order by `msg_time` DESC
```

This way, column `msg_time` will be your original column and `msg_time_local` is your converted column.

You will need proper timezone support configured in MySQL with the time zone tables set up as explained in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time-zone-support.html.